# Reject ssh -L connection unless a corresponding ssh -R exists

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Is there any way to make an SSH server reject a connection that attempts to use port forwarding unless it is directed to an existing reverse tunnel?

To clarify, my intent is to only allow forwarding to sockets that are already been listened on by other clients. So for example I want to allow clients to do something like this:

```
ssh server -N -L X:localhost:Y
```

if and only if someone else has already run something like this:

```
ssh server -N -R Y:localhost:Z
```

If I could also automatically disconnect the forward tunnel when the reverse disconnects that would be even better.

Comment: I read your question three times, but still I have no idea what are you trying to do. Can you explain a bit more, ideally with commands on respective machines?

Comment: @Jakuje: Sure! Does the edit help?

Comment: It seems like a very unlikely feature for someone to implement. What would it do? The equivalent of `netstat` to check if there is a listening socket already open before allowing the forward? The use cases where the proper listening socket might be available later than the `ssh` command runs of perhaps intermittently are probably more important anyway.